# Can I ever clear all Captains in an area?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-war

Is there a scenario in which an area will be completely clear of Captains? Will regular grunts keep replacing slain Captains?

Comment: When time advances new orcs can come into play, this can be done in one of three ways: advance time yourself, complete a nemesis mission or die. So if that doesn't happen, ues that scenario is possible.

Comment: I would think the only real way would be to dominate them all.

Comment: I don't think you can. I've noticed that new captains will emerge to replace killed ones even if you don't do missions or skip time.

You can try and brainwash all of the captains in the area, then get them in one place (not sure it's possible) and use Dispatch to kill them all at the same time. This was possible in Shadow of Mordor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using experience from Shadow of Mordor, grunts would automatically fill vacant spots without notification and time advancing methods. I trialled this quite extensively to my dismay.

I've only briefly played Shadow of War (restricted to Minas Ithril) but I did notice a new captain replace a fallen captain without entering any cutscenes via missions or dying.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Minas Ithil cleared captains]

I know it’s an old thread, but was able to do it. Came looking to see if it grants any additional buffs or bonuses - but doesn’t seem to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).